# apply sum calculated using pandas group by to all elements of group

Tags: python, pandas, group-by, dataframe

I am using pandas module. My dataframe has 5 fields.

Initial 3 fields are account number,month and salary.I want to find percentage of salary received month wise assuming total salary is 100%.
In order to do this I want to use group by on DataFrame. Will group by on account and calculate sum of salaries received in all month's. I have DataFrameGroupBy object original DataFrame but not able to understand how can I divide salary with sum received from group by.

Please suggest how can I apply sum on all rows of one account.

Comment: I am not able to add code here from mobile , I will add working code so that others can see complete picture.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use [`groupby/transform`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) to calculate a value for each row of each group:

```
df['percent salary'] = df.groupby(['account'])['salary'].transform(
                           lambda x: x/x.sum())
```

---

For example,

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
np.random.seed(2015)
df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(10, size=(10, 2)),
                  columns=['account', 'salary'])
df['percent salary'] = df.groupby(['account'])['salary'].transform(lambda x: x/x.sum())

print(df)
```

yields

```
   account  salary  percent salary
0        2       2             0.4
1        9       6             1.0
2        8       5             1.0
3        7       8             0.5
4        0       6             1.0
5        7       8             0.5
6        3       8             1.0
7        6       9             1.0
8        2       3             0.6
9        1       2             1.0
```

Comment: Only one line I am still not able to believe it, just 1 week back I started python and it simply rocks.